# php rsa encryption function returning nothing

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, phpseclib

I am using `phpseclib` for `RSA` encryption http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/.

This is my php code:

```
include('Math/BigInteger.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');


$message="123456";
$private_modulus = "272435F22706FA96DE26E980D22DFF67";
$private_exponent = "158753FF2AF4D1E5BBAB574D5AE6B54D";

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$message = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($message), 256);
$private_modulus = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($private_modulus), 256);
$private_exponent = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($private_exponent), 256);


$rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $private_modulus, 'e' => $private_exponent));
$encryptedText=$rsa->encrypt($message);
echo  $encryptedText;
```

However, `encryptedText` is blank. Any help?

Comment: RSA keys are kinda strange to me. Where did you get this example? And yes, `$encryptedText` is not blank, it is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with public/private keys. By the look of the function `$rsa->loadKey()` comment, first parameter is string, but you have assigned some strange array...

```
/**
 * Loads a public or private key
 *
 * Returns true on success and false on failure (ie. an incorrect password was provided or the key was malformed)
 *
 * @access public
 * @param String $key
 * @param Integer $type optional
 */
function loadKey($key, $type = false)
```

Example of working encrypt/decrypt with random public/private keys :

```
include('_seclib/Math/BigInteger.php');
include('_seclib/Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
extract($rsa->createKey());

# encrypt
$message = '123456';
$rsa->loadKey($publickey);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($message);
var_dump($ciphertext);

# decrypt
$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);
var_dump($rsa->decrypt($ciphertext));
```

See [documentation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/misc_crypt.html) for more info.

Comment: Although the documentation doesn't really mention it phpseclib it looks like phpseclib can support raw RSA keys in the format the OP is trying to use them in. See `CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW` for example.

Comment: True, I have just looked at next method `function _parseKey($key, $type)` where `$key` is still marked/commented as string, but is also used as array in this method.

Answer (score 0):

When an encryption mode isn't explicitely defined it defaults to OAEP. OAEP requires the key be at least 2 * the hash size + 2. The default hash phpseclib uses is sha1, which has a length of 20 bytes. So the key needs to be at least 22 bytes long or 176 bits.

Yours is 16 bytes long or 128 bits.

So you either need to use a larger key or change the encryption mode to use PKCS1 padding. PKCS1 padding requires the modulo be at least 11 bytes.

It'd probably be useful if phpseclib displayed an error when the length of the chosen modulo was insufficient. I'll try to suggeste that to him.

Also, FWIW, textbook RSA doesn't impose any minimum length requirements, but phpseclib doesn't currently implement textbook RSA. I guess you can kinda get it by calling _exponentiate directly but that's the only way.

Textbook RSA is bad because it's vulnerable to certain types of attacks that randomized padding like PKCS1 / OAEP protect against.